# Download full WhatsApp history

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

Is there any way to make backup of WhatsApp history with all emoticons and media? (no .txt file)

I have non-rooted Android 2.2.

Comment: You mean all the conversations you had and all the photos/sounds/videos you had there?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Connect your phone to your computer, search for the Whatsapp directory (just called Whatsapp), and just copy it to your computer. Everything you wanted is stored in that folder.

When you want to restore your backup, you just copy the folder back to the phone **and then** install Whatsapp. You will then be given the option to restore backup.

Comment: Ok. But can I view messages on PC? I don't know how to open that files...

Comment: From a little Google search: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2719741 ; Try this, I never tried that so I can't guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you are non rooted user so titanium backup wont work for you 
 Your history is automatically backuped daily so don't worry 
 still you want to backup u can do by Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chat settings > Backup conversations. 
 else connect your phone to pc and use mobogine to backup your whats app its easy choose your way.

Answer (score -1):

Try to backup the app with data using titanium backup. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Have you seen the part "I have non rooted Android" in the question? TiBu requires the device to be rooted, so this obviously isn't of much help to the OP.